# bitcoin from ebay

Tags: blockchain

I bought a bitcoin on eBay, but my bitcoin wallet is taking FOREVER to sync. How can I see if I own a bitcoin? Do I have to wait probably weeks for the wallet to sync?

Comment: Regardless of your wallet, which you'll need to _spend_ that bitcoins, you can check if it is actually at the specified address using any online tool, such as https://blockchain.info/

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the address to which it was sent via [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info).

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Yes I see it there. Now is my only option to wait for my wallet to sync?

Comment: you could use an online wallet or electrum. those don't need to download the blockchain. But the bitcoin client is more secure if used with encryption (wallet encryption).

Comment: So I have an address in my bit-coin wallet that i sent to the eBay seller. Can I move this address to another wallet before the bit-coin has entered my wallet?

Comment: @user2029574 you can add that address to a new wallet, and you do not need to remove it from the first wallet. Of course it is better not to duplicate addresses in multiple wallets, so yes it is better if you actually move it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how to do that. Basically my bit-coin wallet seems to be stuck on 97% sync even if I leave the computer on over a weekend. I can export the wallet, but since the coin has not yet downloaded I don't think this will work.